# How to enable counter columns in Scylla 1.7

Tags: configuration, scylla

Scylla 1.7 is supposed to introduce [experimental counter columns support](http://www.scylladb.com/2017/04/04/counters/), but the functionality seems disabled by default: trying to create a table with a counter column I get:

```
cassandra.InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Counter support is not enabled"
```

How can I enable it?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can enable counters by adding `experimental: true` to the scylla.yaml

You can read more about 1.7 here http://www.scylladb.com/2017/05/23/scylla-release-version-1-7/

Comment: Please note that as of Scylla 2.0, this is no longer required. Counters are enabled unconditionally and the feature is no longer optional.